# Referencing objects that have yet to be defined

Tags: c++

I've got two objects that need to point to one another... the only problem is that since they are declared in a particular order, one or the other doesn't know about the other object existing. For example:

```
...
#define foobar_h

class Foo {
  Bar* b;
};

class Bar {
  Foo* f;
};

...
```

How can I declare these classes so that they'll be happy referencing one another?

Comment: This is a common question, and the common answer starts with: do you *really* need a cyclic dependency in your code? There are cases where it makes sense, but in most cases it's a hint that the design can be improved. Think about it.

Comment: It's a valid point. I end up doing crap like this as it is currently designed: `float x = (*(*bar).foo).getSignal(*bar);`

Comment: I have a linked list of foos, and each foo points to a linked list of bars. It's a 2D linked list. Each foo contains raw data, each bar contains a separate set of parameters in relation to its particular bar. I need to operate on the bar with the parameters in foo.. so foo just holds a linked list of foos and bars, while bar holds a linked list of bars, and a pointer back to its head (foo). Probably more detail than you cared to know, but that's what's going on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do a pre-declaration:

```
class Bar;

class Foo {
  Bar* b;
};

class Bar {
  Foo* f;
};
```

This makes the compiler know that the type `Bar` is a class, so it can correctly figure out how to represent a pointer to it.

Of course, this only works when the exact layout and size of values of type `Bar` are not needed, if you had tried to embed a value with:

```
class Foo {
  Bar my_bar;
};
```

You had not been able to succeed, but since you used a pointer it's okay. A reference had also worked, since references don't embed the entire object.

Comment: Derp. I knew it was something simple like that. Thanks.

Comment: Note this works for pointers and references but not instance members which need the definition at declaration.

Comment: AJG85: You can't have two classes that contain each other as members though.  It should always be possible to have one class refer to the other only by pointer/reference.

Comment: Those are called _forward-declarations_. Actually, though, they simply are class declarations. (See why at the end of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration/1410632#1410632).)